# How to add custom error message with joi?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, joi

I'm getting an ugly validation message for my schema error (especially for regex).  I want users to create a project name without white spaces. I have made the following schema.

Project: `Joi.string().min(3).regex(/^\S+$/).max(25).required().`

Error message currently looks likes this -> Project" with value " xyz" fails to match the required pattern: `/^\S+$/`. I would like to provide a friendly message instead.

Tried something similar but not working  ->
sheetName:

```
Joi.string().min(3).regex(/^\S+$/).max(25).required().messages({
      "object. regex": `No white space allowed`,
    }),
  };
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `.pattern` and then you can use `object.pattern.base` to set the error message accordingly

```
Joi.string().min(3).pattern(new RegExp(/^\S+$/)).max(25).required().messages({
      "object.pattern.base": `No white space allowed`,
    }),
};
```

See here for more information about, `.pattern` https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectpatternpattern-schema-options